# Blom (or other rank-based) transformation in Java

Tags: java, statistics

I'm trying to implement the Blom transformation in Java, that basically means back transforming ranks to a standard normal distribution.

I'm using the Java Statistical Classes libraries to derive ranks and create a Normal distribution,
however it doesn't seem to provide the proper function for this transformation.

Any idea?

Comment: you can also try asking here http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "it doesn't seem to provide the proper function for this transformation" -- what's missing? What are you looking for that you haven't found? What is the outline of your approach and where is the missing piece?